# Navigate to another Viewcontroller in Custom Table View Cell Button Action

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, uibutton

I have a  TableViewCell where there is a button Zoom Button. When I click to the Zoom button the view will be navigation to PlayerViewController.

(https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikmj4vdfc407ldy/customcell.png)

Here is my Code for the play Button.

```
-(IBAction)downloadAction:(id)sender 
{
            BookPlayerViewController *bookPlayerViewController=[BookPlayerViewController alloc];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookPlayerViewController animated:YES];
}
```

How can I solve this problem?. I am implementing the project using Nib instead of storyboard.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be  BookPlayerViewController *bookPlayerViewController=[BookPlayerViewController alloc]init];

Comment: I tried with BookPlayerViewController *bookPlayerViewController=[BookPlayerViewController alloc]init]; , But it didn't work

Comment: you should try BookPlayerViewController *vcBookPlayerViewController = [[BookPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcBookPlayerViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I  created an outlet property in the tableviewcell class
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *zoomButton;
```

**Then I add the target in the superclass in tableviewCellForRowAtIndex method**

```
[cell.zoomButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigateAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then I take IBAction of  navigateAction  I wrote those actions required to navigate from one ViewController to Another ViewController.

```
-(IBAction)navigateAction:(id)sender
```

{

```
*UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
int indexrow = btn.tag;
NSLog(@"Selected row is: %d",indexrow);

currentBook = [[bookListParser bookListArray] objectAtIndex:indexrow];

KitapDetayViewController *kitapDetayViewController;
if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    kitapDetayViewController = [[KitapDetayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KitapDetayViewController" bundle:Nil];
}

else
{
    kitapDetayViewController = [[KitapDetayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KitapDetayViewController_iPhone4" bundle:Nil];
}
kitapDetayViewController.bookId=currentBook.bookId;
kitapDetayViewController.detailImageUrl = currentBook.detailImageUrl;
kitapDetayViewController.bookAuthor = currentBook.bookAuthor;
kitapDetayViewController.bookName = currentBook.bookName;
kitapDetayViewController.bookDescription = currentBook.bookDescription;
kitapDetayViewController.bookNarrator=currentBook.bookNarrator;
kitapDetayViewController.bookOrderHistory=currentBook.bookOrderDate;
int byte=[currentBook.bookSizeAtByte intValue];
int mb=byte/(1024*1024);
NSString *mbString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mb];
kitapDetayViewController.bookSize=mbString;
kitapDetayViewController.bookOrderPrice=currentBook.priceAsText;
int second=[currentBook.bookDuration intValue];
int minute=(second/60)%60;
int hour=(second/3600)%60;
int sec = second % 60;

NSString *formattedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%d:%d", hour, minute, sec];
kitapDetayViewController.bookDuration=formattedTime;
kitapDetayViewController.chapterNameListArray=self.chapterNameListArray;
// [[bookListParser bookListArray ]release];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:kitapDetayViewController animated:YES];*
```

}

This way I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are not initializing the nib Name. You need to initialize your BookPlayerViewController with the NibName in order to show it,

Using **IB**:

```
BookPlayerViewController *vcBookPlayerViewController = [[BookPlayerViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"BookPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Using **Storyboard**:

```
BookPlayerViewController *vcBookPlayerViewController = [storyboard
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BookPlayerViewController"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try it this way if you're loading nib of nextview

```
BookPlayerViewController *vcBookPlayerViewController = [[BookPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookPlayerViewController" bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcBookPlayerViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the nib check out this code..

```
-(IBAction)downloadAction:(id)sender 
{
            BookPlayerViewController *bookPlayerViewController=[BookPlayerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BookPlayerViewController" bundle:nil];;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookPlayerViewController animated:YES];
}
```